# Can one Match the charachter * and ? using string match in Tcl?

Tags: string, tcl, match

I am trying to get matching of the character * using Tcl string match, and fail, with a preceding backslash and w/o it
I can do it with regexp, but wanted to know if there is a way w/o it.
See Tcl log below, for fail:

```
% puts [ string match {\*} {hop} ]
0
% puts [ string match {\*} {hop*} ]
0
% puts [ string match {*} {hop} ]
1
```

As can be seen using {*} just matches everything, and using {\*} does not match hop*

Answer (score 3):

You are testing that the string *equals* a single `*`.

```
% string match {\*} {hop*} 
0
```

To test that the string *contains* a `*`, you need some more globbing:

```
% string match {*\**} {hop*} 
1
```

or

```
% expr {[string first {*} {hop*}] > -1}
1
```

Comment: Also, to see if there's a `*` at the end, use `{*\*}`